# Is there a way to work with a git repo completely remotely via git CLI?

Tags: git

I do a lot of work which requires me to `clone` a new repository and use `git` to search for specific commits, find out which tag/release a specific commit belongs to, dig up when and where a specific bug was fixed, and so on...

The common thread here is that I rarely need to actually commit or write anything. Right now, my workflow consists of performing a `git clone` and then doing this locally.

This consumes time to download the repo, and uses space up locally. I can access most of the same info usually via  a web UI, but web UIs are not my preference, can be unwieldly and slow, and so on....

Is there a way to do these types of operations *without* making a local copy using the `git` command line tool? I feel that local copies were intended for making `changes` to code, which I don't do for most of my work.

I'm typically interacting with remote repositories stored on GitHub or other public git servers (such as https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils.git;a=summary for example). I run Fedora 31.

Comment: Any sort of ssh access to the server..? Local copies in no way _imply_ making (or pushing) changes. Rather, each repo (and all clones) are effectively standalone, only linked by commits and default upstreams..

Comment: That is, there is no distinction between a git repo only for searching and one that can have new commits added: both are the sum of commits and refs. If just wanting a snapshot, that’s possible - sort of hamstrings looking at revisions or using git tools though.

Comment: Even a clone of a specific branch probably won’t be too useful as any mainline work is probably required or not too far back. Now, if the repo is large because of “many binary files”, using something like git’s LFS may be an option - it also has serious tradeoffs, requires work done to the original repo being cloned, and won’t affect historic files.

Comment: Is it typically the same (presumably large) repo that you work in? If yes, why not keep it and just fetch each time you work on it? Then you don't have to re-clone it every time and the fetch time should be negligible by comparison. Yes this would constantly take up some space, but are you short on space? How much space are we talking about?

Comment: You could use a shadow clone (only clone the latest version) or maybe create your own app by reading the repository or just mount it?

Comment: @TTT unfortunately not the same one - it is many large repos. I just did a check on my working directory in fact, and so far its 22GB in size. I can clear this stuff out periodically, but just was wondering my other options here.

dan1st maybe I could mount somehow, probably depends on where the software is hosted.

Comment: @the_endian if it were me, and I were working in the repos regularly, I'd just leave them be. I would happily dedicate a few hundred GB of space on a drive just so I didn't have to re-clone every time I wanted to run some commands. Also, depending on what you do with the repos, you might be able to get by without a checkout (either using bare or no-checkout). For example, I have a repo that is 3 GB bare, but if I checkout a branch it uses 10GB of space. For digging around you might get by without a checkout. Ultimately though, ssh into an existing copy might be easiest if you can...

Comment: `git` itself doesn't really have remote operations (akin to CVS/SVN), but you may be able to access it on remote host by other means. You mention WebUI... things like GitHub for instance tend to have their own API and expose bunch of information through that.

Comment: Where are your remote repositories stored (e.g., on GitHub, on a server, etc.), and what OS are you using?

Comment: @bk2204 I've added this info to the bottom of the question now.

Answer (score 0):

If your source is major public repositories, then you don't really have much of a choice but to clone the repositories.  GitHub provides an API, and there may be FUSE-based file systems which can mock a real repository, but neither of those are going to be performant, and if you need the Git CLI, then you need a repository.

There is a relatively new option which may decrease your need for disk space at the cost of a network connection: partial clone.  You can clone a repository without any of the blobs by using the `--filter=blob:none` argument to `git clone`.  That will download all of the commits and trees, which usually aren't very large, and fetch the blobs on demand from the remote as you need them.

If you decide to do this, you should be aware of a few things.  One, you should use a reasonably recent Git.  I'd really recommend rebuilding the Fedora 33 or Rawhide package here, since partial clone is relatively new and a decent number of bugs are fixed in each version.  You can also build your own Git, but even as a Git developer, I just use the Debian experimental packages for daily use.

Second, partial clone requires support from the server side.  GitHub has this, but not all hosting providers do.  You may find the server side doesn't support it, in which case you'll just have to fall back to a regular clone, or possible a shallow clone if that meets your needs.